# Translate package+class name to .class filename

Tags: java, class, classpath, bytecode, bcel

I'm writing a program which analyzes `.class` files.  I want to attach package and class name to my output.

My plan is to write a function which takes the package and class name as input and finds the corresponding `.class` file (so the user doesn't have to enter that as well, and can't get it wrong), where 'find' should be read as 'give me some data I can use as arguments for BCEL's `ClassParser` constructor' (either a filename, or a name of a zip file and a name within the zip file).

How do I go about that?  Does java come with something which does that? I understand name resolution to be done in the context of a `CLASSPATH`, so the user should probably supply one of those as well; that's fine.

Note: solutions should **not** execute any code from the `.class` file.  Just the bytes, ma'm ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are using BCEL, everything is already there, see [`ClassPath`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/?org/apache/bcel/util/ClassPath.html):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass;
import org.apache.bcel.util.ClassPath;

public class BcelTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String classPath=System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        // demonstrating with our own class path examplary for an arbitrary path String
        ClassPath cp=new ClassPath(classPath);
        ClassPath.ClassFile cf=cp.getClassFile(BcelTest.class.getName());
        ClassParser p=new ClassParser(cf.getInputStream(), cf.getPath());
        JavaClass jc = p.parse();
        System.out.println(jc);

        // or just using our own system path explicitly
        cf=ClassPath.SYSTEM_CLASS_PATH.getClassFile("java.lang.Object");
        p=new ClassParser(cf.getInputStream(), cf.getPath());
        jc = p.parse();
        System.out.println(jc);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't explicitly state, though I meant to convey, that class resolution should be done in a classpath supplied from the user, which may be different from the one my code is running under/with.  I think all I need to do is give different arguments to `new ClassPath(...)`.  With that in place, this looks very promising!

Comment: I assumed that you want the ability to provide an arbitrary class path; that’s why I chose the constructor in the example as otherwise the `ClassPath.SYSTEM_CLASS_PATH` would work for the example as well. Note that the `ClassPath` constructed with the explicit path does not find the system classes as they are not reachable from the explicit class path, you would have to [provide `SYSTEM_CLASS_PATH` as a parent](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/util/ClassPath.html#ClassPath-org.apache.bcel.util.ClassPath-java.lang.String-) for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the classfile, just replace every / in the class name with the directory separator for your system and append .class.

If you want to go from Java class name to bytecode class name, most classes are pretty simple. Prepend the package + '.' and replace '.' with '/'. For inner and nested classes, I'm not sure if there is a simple algorithm.

Comment: I don't have the class file.  Say I run my project on itself.  It resides in `~/whatever/` with `main()` in `invalid/jonaskoelker/Main.java` and my classpath is `.:/usr/share/java/bcel.jar`.  The algorithm I want, when run on `org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser` should return two values, `/usr/share/java/bcel.jar` and `org/apache/bcel/classfile/ClassParser.class` (however you do two values in java, e.g. apache-commons pair).  Is there a built-in thing which does something in that direction?

Comment: @JonasKölker What if the same class appears in multiple Jars?

Comment: I want the one java would load, which I assume and seem to recall is the one first found on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank the fine folks in `irc://freenode.org/##java` for guiding me towards the following recipe:

```
// replace 'Throwable' with something else in production code :-)
JavaClass recipe() throws Throwable {
    URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {
            new URL("file:///usr/share/java/js.jar"),
        });
    String path = "org/mozilla/classfile/ByteCode.class";
    InputStream resource = loader.getResourceAsStream(path);
    String fake_filename = "<" + path + ">";
    ClassParser classparser = new ClassParser(resource, fake_filename);
    JavaClass java_class = classparser.parse();
    // System.out.format("%s\n", jc);
    return java_class;
}
```

One could de-hardcode the classpath and the value of `path` by computing strings in the right format based on user input.

I'm going to use the answer I have accepted because it takes less work on my part, but I want to mention this answer because it is more generally applicable (i.e. with fewer dependencies).